# geckodriver not opening firefox on ubuntu using selenium with django

Tags: python, django, selenium, ubuntu

I have spent the whole day tackling this problem. my selenium code works on windows perfectly with chromedriver and geckodriver,i needed celery and my best option was to switch to my ubuntu os(version 20.) The page were it is supposed to display the scraped data shows message:connection refused. geckodriver is version 26
This is the error.

```
File "/home/maro/Desktop/crypto/cert/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/maro/Desktop/crypto/cert/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/maro/Desktop/crypto/cert/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/maro/Desktop/crypto/forex/views.py", line 80, in pricelist
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/bin/geckodriver')
  File "/home/maro/Desktop/crypto/cert/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/home/maro/Desktop/crypto/cert/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/maro/Desktop/crypto/cert/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/maro/Desktop/crypto/cert/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/maro/Desktop/crypto/cert/lib/python3.b/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: connection refused
```

i have updated my firefox from version 75 to 80 and still no change. i have changed driver path multiple times and still and the error still remains the same.

this is my geckodriver log

```
1594416320001   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileS5CJqR"
```

the geckodriver is executable, i have also checked the hosts to see if localhost was attached to 127.0.... url and yes, it was. i am completely confused

here is my view.py

```
import time
import selenium
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
def pricelist(request):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/bin/geckodriver')
    driver.get('')
    data = []
    while not data:

        
        for elm in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-field=CPT]"):
            if elm.text and elm.text != '-':
                data.append(elm.text)
                
            
        time.sleep(3)
           
    context = {
        "price": 123,
        "mydata": data
    }

    return render(request, 'pricelist.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gotten it to work. I switched to chromedriver, I encountered a similar problem and discovered that the chromedriver uses the same port as my Django app. I changed the port for my Django app to 8001 with `python manage.py runserver 8001`